# Php regex word lookahead

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to scrape a webpage for a person's name and am having trouble factoring in the possibility that a middle name may also be present. For example, if i am trying to match the name "John Smith" on a webpage and that page has the name with a middle name included (for example John Mark Smith or John M Smith or John M. Smith or JohnM.Smith), the search will turn up empty even though technically the first and last name are mentioned together on the page.

Is there a regex that can take into account a one word hop in the middle of matching the name? The name is in the variable:

```
$fullname = "John Smith";
```

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Try: `^John.*?Smith$` see: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3jf

Comment: First and foremost, what has you tried so far?  Are you trying to use regex on entire page content or are you using DOM parser to look for this name within a certain DOM element?

Comment: I am using curl to get back the text on the page.

Comment: Well, the `.*?` part anyways... you likely won't want the `^` and `$` if you are scraping a page.

Comment: Define what you'd find acceptable as _"a one word hop"_, and add that in: `/John (whateverthathopis )Smith/` (you might want to use `\s`'s instead of the 2 spaces in there).

Comment: alfasin's answer is unreliable, because the page may contain a John  Jones followed by a Sam Smith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been slightly expanded to include the possible reverse order.

Try:

```
(John ?[\w\.]* ?Smith|Smith ?[\w\.]* ?John)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this (or something similar):
replace the space with " ?[a-zA-Z.]* ?"
    `John ?[a-zA-Z\.]* ?Smith`
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3jh

Comment: I think that works well but what about the case where the name can be written in a slightly different order. (M.Smith John or M. Smith John)?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/(John.*?Smith|Smith.*?John)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

See here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3jj

Comment: I believe this has the same problem as alfasin's response in the comments above. it would match something like John Jones Sam Smith